# Read a file and convert it to an array (Java)

Tags: java

So I have a collection of phrases that are separated by newlines and I would like to populate an array with these phrases. This is what I have so far:

```
   Scanner s;
   s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Phrases.txt")));
   for(i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
   {
   s.nextLine() = array[i];
   }
```

Is there a fast and simple way to just populate an array with phrases separated by newlines?

Comment: are you aware that this code of yours is not populating any array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment should be reverse: -

```
array[i] = s.nextLine();
```

And, I think you should fill your array based on the input received from the file. Here you are receving input based on the length of your pre-declared array. I mean, since you are using an `array`, your size is fixed. So you can only populate it with a fixed number of phrases.

---

A better way would be to use an `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, you can populate your arraylist, based on the phrases you get from your file. You don't need to pre-define the size. It increases in size dynamically.

And to add phrases, you would do: -

```
phrases.add(s.nextLine());
```

With a `while` loop to read till `EOF`.

```
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    phrases.add(s.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how many phrases you're likely to have (I suspect), I would populate an `ArrayList<String>` and convert it to an array using [ArrayList.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) once you're done. I'd perhaps keep it as a Java collection, however, for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You have the assignment operation inverted (`array[i]` should be set to `s.nextLine()`, not the other way around. Also, it would be best to modify the for loop to terminate when no more lines exist:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length && s.hasNextLine() ;i++) {
     array[i] = s.nextLine()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time with `Scanner`. `BufferedReader` is just fine. Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Phrases.txt")));
LinkedList<String> phrases = new LinkedList<String>();
while(br.ready()) {
    phrases.add(br.readLine());
}
String[] phraseArray = phrases.toArray(new String[0]);
```

By the way it's **important** to use `LinkedList` not `ArrayList` if the file is large. That way you only create one array at the end. Otherwise you will have a lot of large array creation and wasted memory.

Comment: Never used `BufferedReader.ready`. Is there really a method with that name? Did I missed that?

Comment: [BufferedReader.ready()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29) it does exist!

Comment: @durron597.. Man.. Thanks. Never knew of that. Actaully I mostly use `Scanner`. With BufferedReader I used `null` check with `readLine()`. :(

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a 1 liner with [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org) and specifically [`FileUtils.readLines()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29)

```
FileUtils.readLines(myFile).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. it has to be

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
   {
   array[i]=s.nextLine();
   }

array[i] = value; // the value would be assigned into the array at index i.
```

However, a better option would be to use a List implementing classes such as ArrayList which gives you an advantage of dynamic size.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(s.nextLine(());
```

Comment: this is the answer that gets accepted? It doesn't work becaues you don't know how the big the array is going to be! And it doesn't correctly parameterize `ArrayList`

Comment: @durron597.. Actually `ArrayList` is correctly parameterized. Just that it will only work in `Java 7` - (A Diamond operator) it is called.

Comment: @durron597 i am confused. `It doesn't work becaues you don't know how the big the array is going to be!` ?? the only thing wrong in this answer is the dimond problem, which would perfectly work in java 7.

Comment: @durron597 update yourself about `The diamond in java 7` here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I don't assume everyone is on Java 7 yet. Also your code doesn't declare a size for the value of `array`, so it will `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` if the file is too large

Comment: @durron597 if you observe, i dint declare the array either, so why not simply just say `your code wouldn't compile`. i was only giving the OP an explanation about how to assign a value to an array, as thats what the question is. please read properly before just bashing at anyone .